# Trouble reconciling new account in Quickbooks - why is starting balance zero

Tags: quickbooks

I created a new checking account in QB 2021 Desktop.  I want to start the fiscal year with 9/1/2021.  So I created a general journal entry with a debit to the checking account for the balance in the account on 8/31/21. But when I go to reconcile the account with the 9/30/21 statement, QB has the starting balance as $0.00.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: does [this video](https://youtu.be/TRKehiVKnvY) help?

Answer (score 1):

The Account Reconciliation screen should show you ALL of the unreconciled transactions for that account, for the period from Day 1 (however that is defined in your system) until 30 September (or whatever alternative date you specify as the Period End).

One of those transactions will be the *Opening Balances* transaction dated 31 August.  It's just a transaction, like all of the other transactions that you recorded for September.  So accept it as a legitimate transaction on your Reconciliation screen, and the account should reconcile properly.